# vagrantのNFS mountでタイムアウトになってしまう。

Tags: windows, network, vagrant, virtualbox

vagrantでNFS mountする設定を行っているのですが、vagrant up時にタイムアウトして失敗してしまいます。

ホスト側（windows10）のファイアウォールを停止すると正常に立ち上がります。
ですので新しいルールを設定する必要があると思うのですが、上手く設定できません。

どのように設定したら良いでしょうか。

vagrantで起動しているクライアントはcentos 7.4、vagrantのversionは1.9.3です。

以下、vagrant up時のメッセージです。
※IPとディレクトリはアスタリスクで潰しています。

```
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit nfs mounting file.
[NFS] Status: running
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp,vers=3,udp,nolock 192.168.**.*:/C/*****/***** /var/www/*****

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Comment: NFSサーバ周りの情報（NFSサーバはホストのWin10？vagrantで起動しているクライアントは？）等も追記してもらうと、回答の手掛かりになるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ホストはwin10です、vagrantで起動しているクライアントはcentos 7.4、vagrantのversionは1.9.3です。ヒントになると良いのですが。